# How to mock final class with Powermockito?

Tags: android, unit-testing, powermock

I have final class.

```
@Mock
Response<Void> response;

@Test
public void removeStoreSuccess(){
    when(app.getApiService()).thenReturn(service);
    when(service.removeFavoriteStore(anyObject())).thenReturn(Observable.just(response));

    presenter.removeStore(favoriteStore);
}
```

> org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException: 
>   Cannot mock/spy class retrofit2.Response
>   Mockito cannot mock/spy following:
>     - final classes
>     - anonymous classes
>     - primitive types

How to mock Response class with Powermockito?

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

Try to follow these steps to fix this issue:

1. Update your project with latest Mockito version (as of now it's 2.8.+)
2. Create a text file, name it "org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker" and place it to .../src/test/resources/mockito-extensions folder
3. Add this line "mock-maker-inline" to that file